# ActiveJDBC insert without prepared statement

Tags: java, activejdbc

I'm trying to use ActiveJDBC with a DB whose driver does not support the `Connection.prepareStatement(String, String[])` method.  I'm getting the following exception when trying to insert:

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver]Unsupported method: Connection.prepareStatement(String, String[]), query: INSERT INTO ...
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb9.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb8.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb8.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.BaseConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.execInsert(DB.java:597)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.insert(Model.java:2618)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.save(Model.java:2552)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.saveIt(Model.java:2477)
    ...
```

Some other forms of prepareStatement are supported, e.g. `prepareStatement (String)`, `prepareStatement (String, int)`, etc.

Is there anything I can do to convince ActiveJDBC not to use the unsupported statement?

Comment: The `String[]` is for auto-generated keys. Do you need the auto-generated key values returned?

Comment: No, I don't. All I'm doing in the code is `m = new Model();`, populate it, then `m.saveIt();`, there are no autogenerated columns in the model. ActiveJDBC calls the `prepareStatement` method internally [here](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/DB.java#L625)

Comment: what database/driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using an OpenEdge RDBMS and their proprietary driver `com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver`, it's a legacy DB I have to interface with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/DB.java) , this is pretty much hard coded. So from the top of my mind you could either request a change in ActiveJDBC or go ahead wrapping your "flawed" Connection into a custom implementation and overriding this `prepareStatement(String, String[])`

```
public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String qry, String[] autoIdColumns) {
  return delegate.prepareStatement(qry);
}
```

Google returned some ideas for [ConnectionWrapper](https://code.google.com/p/lindenb/source/browse/trunk/src/java/org/lindenb/sql/ConnectionWrapper.java?r=481) implementations out there.

Comment: How would I feed such wrapped Connection into AJ? Is that going to be something to do with using `Base.open(DataSource dataSource)`?

Comment: I'm not that deep in AJ. But that seems about right - if you pass in DataSource then that DataSource will in turn create the connections. where do you get DataSource from?

Comment: No idea actually, I haven't used DataSoruces so far, it was the only thing I could see in AJ API that seemed it would allow overriding Connection. I'll dig into that, thanks @Jan

Comment: See how to create a DataSouce here: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/mock/MockDataSource.java

and: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/DataSourceTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at databases supported by ActiveJDBC: http://javalite.io/activejdbc#supported-databases. Each one is thoroughly tested.